# EntityFramework save with constraints

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constraints

I have a DB that has constraints on non-nullable fields.

Let's look at just one: ModifiedDate.

The constraint defaults to getdate() when not supplied a value in an INSERT command.

My code is using Entity Framework so I craft up an entry object, create a datetime instance, set its ModifiedDate field, then execute context.SaveChanges() and it works fine.

However, if I create the object and don't set entry.ModifiedDate then context.SaveChanges() fails before the constraint could set a default value

Comment: Non-nullable field should have value. So assign default value at database level instead of entity framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your entity class you could annotate your `ModifiedDate` property with the following:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed)]
public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
```

From BOL: [DatabaseGenerated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#DatabaseGenerated)

> An important database features is the ability to have computed
>   properties. If you're mapping your Code First classes to tables that
>   contain computed columns, you don't want Entity Framework to try to
>   update those columns. But you do want EF to return those values from
>   the database after you've inserted or updated data. You can use the
>   DatabaseGenerated annotation to flag those properties in your class
>   along with the Computed enum.

Comment: You can also do this from the .edmx designer. Select your DateTime column and go to properties and change StoreGeneratedPattern from None to Computed.

Comment: This worked perfectly! However, we are going with the db-first approach so is there any way EF would scaffold the models with this annotation? The reason I ask is because there are a lot of tables and each have a ModifiedDate and SysModifiedUser field.

Comment: @toadfromgrove Guessing you're using EF6 where default constraints aren't persisted? You could create partial classes for your entities that sets the property as a workaround.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Yes, I just checked and it's EF 6.1.3. In NuGet it shows 6.1.3 as the latest stable version. Is there a newer version that does take constraints into account when scaffolding?

Comment: I believe EF7 will do, but don't quote me on that.